# Restart nested loop in python after condition is met

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two ranges:
range_1 (0,10)
range_2 (11, 40)

I want to create a **list of tuples** from the two ranges above (range_1 and range_2) if the **sum** of any of the two elements in the two ranges is an **even number**.

Thus 0 from range_1 and 12 from range_2 = 12 which is even, the same with 1 from range_1 and 13 from range_2 = 14 which is even.

However I don't want to go through all the elements in range_2. Only 5 successful attempts are needed, then immediately I have to go back to the second iteration in range_1.

Thus for the first iteration:

```
(0, 12, 12), (0, 14, 14), (0, 16, 16), (0, 18, 18), (0, 20, 20)
```

then we go to the second iteration:

```
(1, 11, 12), (1, 13, 14), (1, 15, 16), (1, 17, 18), (1, 19, 20)
```

and so on till 9 in range_1:

```
(9, 11, 20), (9, 13, 22), (9, 15, 24), (9, 17, 26), (9, 19, 28)
```

Here is my code, which goes through all the elements, which is obviously wrong, because it goes through all the elements in range_2!

```
list_1 = []

for i in range(10):
    for j in range(11,40):
        if (i+j)%2 == 0:
            list_1.append((i, j, (i+j)))
```

Comment: I don't understand why the second range goes up to 40? You know ahead of time that the last value used will be either 19 or 20. Just set the upper limit appropriately. You can also pass `2` as a third argument to `range` to get only every other number from the range, and use math to decide whether to start it at `11` or `12`.

Comment: This is a very simple example to make my question simple to understand. In reality, the problem is thus: I have two text files, one is very large, and the other is small, I want to match 5 examples from the large to every word in the small file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just store a counter so that if you reach five then you break out of your nested for-loop:

```
list_1 = []
for i in range(10):
    counter = 0
    for j in range(11,40):
        if (i+j)%2 == 0:
            list_1.append((i, j, (i+j)))
            counter += 1
            if counter == 5:
                break
```

which gives `list_1` as:

```
[(0, 12, 12), (0, 14, 14), (0, 16, 16), (0, 18, 18), (0, 20, 20),
 (1, 11, 12), (1, 13, 14), (1, 15, 16), (1, 17, 18), (1, 19, 20),
 (2, 12, 14), (2, 14, 16), (2, 16, 18), (2, 18, 20), (2, 20, 22),
 (3, 11, 14), (3, 13, 16), (3, 15, 18), (3, 17, 20), (3, 19, 22),
 (4, 12, 16), (4, 14, 18), (4, 16, 20), (4, 18, 22), (4, 20, 24),
 (5, 11, 16), (5, 13, 18), (5, 15, 20), (5, 17, 22), (5, 19, 24),
 (6, 12, 18), (6, 14, 20), (6, 16, 22), (6, 18, 24), (6, 20, 26),
 (7, 11, 18), (7, 13, 20), (7, 15, 22), (7, 17, 24), (7, 19, 26),
 (8, 12, 20), (8, 14, 22), (8, 16, 24), (8, 18, 26), (8, 20, 28),
 (9, 11, 20), (9, 13, 22), (9, 15, 24), (9, 17, 26), (9, 19, 28)]
```

---

It should be noted that this is not the most efficient way to go about creating your data structure. Clearly only ever other `j`-value generated in the inner for-loop will be used, which is wasteful.

Therefore you could specify a step for the `j` for-loop of `2` so that only other `j`-value is considered. However, you must be careful with the starting value now. If you were to always start at `11` and step in `2`s then you would only get odd `j`-values and these could *never* combine with the current `i`-value to give an even number if `i` was even. Therefore you would have to change the `j` for-loop to start at `12` if `i` is even and `11` if `i` is odd.

Comment: Thanks Joe, your answer works perfectly! Thanks also for your notes about the data structure, I will make sure to take it into account.

Answer (score 0):

If you're smart about creating your range, you can simplify the algorithm. Use a *step* to make the range skip every other `j`, adjust the *start* based on whether `i` is even, and set the *end* to 21 since it will only ever get that high.

```
list_1 = []
for i in range(10):
    start = 12 if i % 2 == 0 else 11
    for j in range(start, 21, 2):
        list_1.append((i, j, i+j))
    print(list_1[-5:])  # For testing
```

First two lines of output:

```
[(0, 12, 12), (0, 14, 14), (0, 16, 16), (0, 18, 18), (0, 20, 20)]
[(1, 11, 12), (1, 13, 14), (1, 15, 16), (1, 17, 18), (1, 19, 20)]
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, actually this is a hypothetical example, in reality I really don't know the range I am working with! That's why I specified I only need 5 successful attempts, after that the inner loop has to stop, and the outer loop has to start where it left.

Comment: @Akbar Welcome! OK then Joe's answer should work for you. And you might want to add that info to the question, to avoid other people trying to optimize the math, which is not really what you want.

Answer (score 0):

As others have commented, you can simplify the problem quite a bit by constructing ranges that accomodate what you're trying to do.  Here it is as a nested comprehension:

```
[(i, j, i+j) for i in range(0, 10) for j in range((11 if i % 2 else 12), 21, 2)]
```